# Inequality for Expected Value of Product

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{P}, \mathcal{F})$ be a probability space, and let $\mathbb{E}$ denote the expected value operator.

Consider the random variables $f: \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1,2\}$ and $g: \Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$, where $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the expected value of the product, namely
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ f(\cdot) g(\cdot) \right] := \int_{\Omega} f(\omega) g(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d \omega). $$

Now if $f$ and $g$ are independent random variables, then $\mathbb{E}[f(\cdot) g(\cdot)] = \mathbb{E}[f(\cdot)] \mathbb{E}[g(\cdot)]$.

I am wondering about conditions under which $\mathbb{E}[f(\cdot) g(\cdot)] \geq \mathbb{E}[f(\cdot)] \mathbb{E}[g(\cdot)]$.

Additional Assumption: $\mathbb{E}[g(\cdot)] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[f(\cdot)]$.

Comment: What about _covariance_ being positive?

Comment: Of course, because $\mathbb{E}[ f g ] = \mathbb{E}[f] \mathbb{E}[g] + \text{Cov}(x,y)$. But this is just a definition, not an additional condition on $f$ and $g$.

Comment: And what are $x$ and $y$ in your response to my comment?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that, for every $\omega$ and $\omega'$ in $\Omega$,
$$
(f(\omega)-f(\omega'))\cdot(g(\omega)-g(\omega'))\geqslant0.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that assuming $\mathbb{E}[g] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[f]$ may be useful?

Comment: This is quite unrelated since one can always shift $f$ or $g$ by a constant without changing the direction of the inequality.

Comment: Is this a necessary condition?

Answer (score 3):

The case when *f* and *g* are increasing functions, for which the inequality holds, is well explained in Appendix 9.9, titled "Verification of Antithetic Variable Approach When Estimating the Expected Value of Monotone Functions", of the book Simulation by Sheldon M. Ross, 5th Ed. Academic Press, 2012.

Comment: "$f$ and $g$ are increasing functions" is not very meaningful. What matters is that they change together, in the same direction, which is the condition given by @Did